# How to skip *.json files with dep5 when creating reuse annotations?

Tags: glob, licensing, reusability

I have some *.json files in my root folder, e.g.

```
.prettierrc.json 
.settings.default.json 
.stylelintrc.json 
babel.config.json 
package.json
```

When creating [reuse annotations](https://reuse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#annotate) with a command

```
python -m reuse annotate --copyright="Foo" --copyright-style=symbol --merge-copyrights --license=AGPL-3.0-or-later --skip-unrecognised --skip-existing --recursive .
```

I would like to skip all *.json files.

In order to do so, I created a dep5 file:

```
.reuse/dep5
```

with following content:

```
Format: https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/

Files: *.json
Copyright: 2024 Foo
License: AGPL-3.0-or-later
```

If I run `python -m reuse lint`, I get the result that I am already REUSE compliant.

However, the `reuse annotate` command still creates **unwanted, extra license files** for each of the *.json files, even when using the `--skip-existing` option.

```
.prettierrc.json 
.prettierrc.json.license
.settings.default.json 
.settings.default.json.license 
.stylelintrc.json 
.stylelintrc.json.license
babel.config.json 
babel.config.json .license
package.json
package.json.license
```

=> How do I need to adapt the [dep5 File glob pattern](https://dep-team.pages.debian.net/deps/dep5/#files-field), the reuse command etc. to avoid this?

I also tried following variants for the glob pattern:

```
./*.json
/*.json
```

I also tried to specify explicit file names, separated by spaces.

Comment: Maybe its not supported or a bug. I created an issue ticket: https://github.com/fsfe/reuse-tool/issues/894